# how to automatically write curl output to a new file

Tags: unix, curl, command-line

I am using `cURL` to retrieve stock information back to the terminal window on my Mac using the yahoo finance api.

i.e. I type:

```
curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1'
```

and it prints the output (in this instance the last trade price in the command line)

It works terrific, but I would like to know how to get this output automatically written to a stock.txt file located on my desktop without any manual intervention upon the execution of the original cURL command.

Thus after I type the curl  query that contains the stock ticker, I get the value written in the terminal window and the txt file.

Comment: Hi, the "curl -s..." command no longer works, do you know what the updated url is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1' > ~/Desktop/stock.txt && more ~/Desktop/stock.txt`

Comment: the && more, just for my knowledge what is this doing

Comment: The `&& more` command tells the shell to wait until output is complete to ~/Desktop/stock.txt, and then to open it up using the command `more` (which just views a file). The solution below uses the `tee` command which does this in one step.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `curl ... | tee ~/Desktop/stock.txt`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `-o`/`--output` option:

```
curl -o users.json https://reqres.in/api/users
```